# PDFDate format for UTC in iTexPDFt and iTextSharp

Tags: itext

In iTextPDF 5.5.8 for Java when creating a PDFDate in UTC timeZone, I get the following format:

**(D:20160212073102Z)**

Whereas in iTextSharp (older version) I get for UTC the format:

**(D:20160212082328+00'00')**

While Adobe Reader can handle both Versions, one of our Adobe Acrobat Signing plugins requires the first Version and can not handle +00'00' (it accepts +01'00' though).

Now my question: Does anyone know, how we could make iTextSharp produce the first Version? (D:20160212073102Z)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you show for the older iTextSharp version

```
(D:20160212082328+00'00')
```

is wrong, the specification clearly says:

> A PLUS SIGN as the value of the O field signifies that
>   local time is later than UT, a HYPHEN-MINUS signifies that local time is earlier than UT, and the LATIN
>   CAPITAL LETTER Z signifies that local time is equal to UT

Thus, the `Z` form has to be used for UTC.

Thus, you had better try and update to the current iTextSharp and test again. If there still is the wrong form, update your question accordingly. Such a bug would surely be fixed soon.